# Cannot create stored procedure from .sql file - JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, ant, jdbc

I am trying to execute a .sql file during the installation of my web project by using jdbc. 2 options suggested from google: either parsing the script manually (by splitting the ";" character) or using ant. I prefer the simple way so ant is a good choice. This is the code i use to set up the database:

```
public void executeSql(String sqlFilePath) {
        final class SqlExecuter extends SQLExec {
            public SqlExecuter() {
                Project project = new Project();
                project.init();
                setProject(project);
                setTaskType("sql");
                setTaskName("SQL Init");
            }
        }

        SqlExecuter executer = new SqlExecuter();
        executer.setSrc(new File(sqlFilePath));
        executer.setDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ;
        executer.setPassword("123456");
        executer.setUserid("root");
        executer.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc");
        executer.execute();
    }
```

The code working fine until it meets the part of creating the procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE LOG (IN period INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_archive
        SELECT * FROM ablog
            WHERE log_date < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL period DAY);
    DELETE FROM ablog
        WHERE log_date < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL period DAY);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

and give this error:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE LOG(IN period INT) BEGIN INSERT INTO log_archi' at line 1

if i remove the stored procedure part, then it will run well. The sql file is also executed succesfully from the mysql command prompt. Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a tool like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/create_stored_procedure). It supports mysql, there are some minor issues though.

Comment: I think this is the only way to execute the stored procedure from separated file. Thank for you link

Comment: @bubuzz : No, any one can load an sql, format according to SQL engine and then call JDBC. Liquibase does it better :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?46,271411,271411

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LOG (period INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_archive
        SELECT * FROM ablog
            WHERE log_date < CURRENT_DATE- INTERVAL period DAY;
    DELETE FROM ablog
        WHERE log_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL period DAY;
END
```

---

you can put delimiters if need be to run it in the commandline 
`mysql>\. yoursqlfile.sql`
It has just worked from commandline with `delimiter //` and at `END//`.

---

commandline :

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE LOG (period INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_archive
        SELECT * FROM ablog
            WHERE log_date < CURRENT_DATE- INTERVAL period DAY;
    DELETE FROM ablog
        WHERE log_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL period DAY;
END//
```

---

hope it helps abit

Comment: yes, i also tried it after creating the question. I also get this error message Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. Obviously the code without the delimiter run well when i create a String containing it and use executeUpdate

Comment: @bubuzzz have you checked this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html they have example too

Comment: thank you for your link. I also tried it. Maybe this could be the reason why it does not work http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58425. Hopfully it gonna help some one. Still cannot find the solution, though

Comment: as a solution you can put your procedures inside a SQL file and run it  before deploying your application. That´s a normal way to do it too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use only one delimiter (eg. `\\` or I used `$$`) and don't change mid script (no `DELIMITER XX`) then you can run reasonably complex scripts.

```
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, password);
statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
for (String sqlpart : sqlFileContents.split("\\$\\$"))
{
    if (!sqlpart.trim().isEmpty())
        statement.addBatch(sqlpart);
}
statement.executeBatch();
```

For example

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Log $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Log (period INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_archive
        SELECT * FROM ablog
            WHERE log_date < CURRENT_DATE- INTERVAL period DAY;
    DELETE FROM ablog
        WHERE log_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL period DAY;
END $$
```