# Create Stored Procedure from File

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, liquibase

I am trying to execute a whole directory of `.SQL` files in Java.

I'm struggling to execute a stored procedure. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363580/cannot-create-stored-procedure-from-sql-file-jdbc) so far (the most helpful) including a dead link, sadly. I have downloaded liquibase also, but I cannot figure out how I should use it for this purpose.

In my current code, I split the files including procedures into different statements:

*(Statements split in a Vector[String] and executed in a for loop)*

Example:

```java
//File f;
//Statement st;
Vector<String> vProcedure = getProcedureStatements(f, Charset.defaultCharset(), "//");
for (Iterator<String> itr = vProcedure.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
    st.execute(itr.next());
System.out.println(f.getName() + " - done executing.");
```

The Vector contains the four elements *(see SQL-Code #SPLIT x)*.

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Add_Position`; #SPLIT 1
DELIMITER // #SPLIT 2
CREATE PROCEDURE `Add_Position`
(
    IN iO_ID INT,
    IN iCID INT,
    IN iWID INT,
    IN iA INT
)
BEGIN
    #statements;
END
// #SPLIT  3
DELIMITER ; #SPLIT 4
```

[Result](http://i57.tinypic.com/23vyeio.jpg) when trying to execute #SPLIT 2:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //' at line 1
```

**Q: Could anyone tell me if there's a exteral library I could use, or how liquibase does work ? I can't get it to work the JDBC-way.**

Comment: Just to understand, your splitting the .sql file into indivual statements and then executing each one.  What error are you getting?  What JDBC call are you using? Here's some example JDBC code http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-jdbc-java-to-dynamically-create-a-stored-procedure/171

Comment: What do you mean with _"I can't get it to work the JDBC-way"_

Comment: By the way, this has been fixed 16h ago. I removed all delimiter statements and read in the whole procedure statement in "getProcedureStatements". That way it executes in JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `DELIMITER \\` is not actually SQL - it is a command that is interpreted by the mysql command-line tool (and possibly also their GUI tool), but if you pass it straight to the execution engine, you will get this syntax error.

Unfortunately, Liquibase uses `;` as the default statement separator, so it is difficult to get this sort of thing to work using SQL files and Liquibase. I have put in a pull request to allow setting the delimiter from the Liquibase command line - see https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/361.