# Is there any way to execute stored procedure in .sql file from java code

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure saved on local file system in .sql file.
Ex. StoredProcedure.sql

I am looking for a way to read and execute this stored procedure file from java code.

We can execute database stored procedure using

```
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call ProcedureName(?)}");
    cs.setInt(1, 1);
    cs.execute();
```

I am looking for way to pass "new File(sqlFilePath)" instead of "call ProcedureName"

Sample Contents of StoredProcedure.sql

```
    USE [DBName]
    GO
    DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ProcedureName]
            @p1 = 1

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO
```

Comment: Goahead. It can be done.

Comment: A`java.sql.CallableStatement` is used to call stored procedures in a database.- google ;)

Comment: Yes thats correct using CallableStatement we can call stored procedures in DATABASE. My stored procedure is in .sql file on local system. I need a way to read that sql file and execute stored procedure.

Comment: You can just use a `FileReader` to read the plain text as a string. Then execute this string using the default execute method.

Comment: @Blacktempel can you share your code of getProcedureStatements method in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781769/create-stored-procedure-from-file.  I am trying to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stored Procedure query directly inside your java code file instead of referring to as sql file.

Or you can simply read the content of the file and store it to a variable.